# Overriding attribute from child class erases it from trait in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

If a class inherits from a trait, and they both share a parent, it seems as if overriding an attribute of the parent will make it inaccessible from the trait. Namely

```
class TestClass(arg: String) extends Parent(arg) with TestTrait {
  override val foo = "hey"
}

trait TestTrait extends Parent {
  val bar = foo
}

abstract class Parent(arg: String) {
  val foo = arg
}
```

Then running

```
val c = new TestClass("hello")
c.bar
```

will return `null`. This seems like counterintuitive behavior for me. Could anyone explain what the general inheritance rules and rationale behind them are to me?

EDIT: Thanks for the responses. However, I'm still confused as to why this works then:

```
class TestClass(arg: String) extends Parent(arg) with TestTrait {
  // override val foo = "hey"
}

trait TestTrait extends Parent {
  val bar = foo
}

abstract class Parent(arg: String) {
  val foo = arg
}
```

Running the same as before will successfully produce "hello". Based on the explanations provided, I would've have expected `null` again. Sorry for not provided this context in the original phrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `val` s are evaluated in sequence, meaning **both** in-type declaration sequence, and inheritance declaration sequence.

If there would be no `override`, `bar` would be evaluated based on the definition from the `Parent` constructor, since it is executed before the `TestTrait` constructor (because `TestTrait` is a subtype of `Parent`). So, `bar` would have whatever value it has in `Parent`.

---

However, since you override `foo` in `TestClass`, **the evaluation takes place only once `TestClass`'s constructor gets invoked**, and this is after `TestTrait`.

The best rationale I could find for this in the SLS is [within 5.3.1](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#constructor-definitions):

> The signature and the self constructor invocation of a constructor
>   definition are type-checked and evaluated in the scope which is in
>   effect at the point of the enclosing class definition, augmented by
>   any type parameters of the enclosing class and by any early
>   definitions of the enclosing template. **The rest of the constructor
>   expression is type-checked and evaluated as a function body in the
>   current class.**

(emph. mine)

Implying the following pseudocode:

```scala
class TestClass(arg: String) extends Parent(arg) with TestTrait {
   Parent(arg) //arg is ignored, since TestClass overrides foo. 
   TestTrait() //foo is still null at this point
   override val foo = "hey"
}
```

Essentially boiling down to the same case as:

```
class A {
   val a: String = b //a will be null, since b is not yet evaled
   val b = "A"
}
```

(only without the luxury of a compiler warning)

---

In hindsight, this quirk is in fact hinted by Scala's language feature of [**early definitions**](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#early-definitions). With your code, its use would look like the following:

```scala
class TestClass(arg: String) extends {
  override val foo = "hey"
} with Parent(arg) with TestTrait

trait TestTrait extends Parent {
  val bar = foo
}

abstract class Parent(arg: String) {
  val foo = arg
}

scala> new TestClass("hello").bar
res0: String = hey
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't think explains the additional context provided in my edit.

Comment: @dzy : you are right, the rationale given in the original answer was completely wrong. Sorry! After some research, I've rewritten it, with hopefully more fidelity to reality.

Answer (score 1):

That's because constructors are executed top to bottom (from less derived type to most derived type).

Which means `TestTrait` is constructed before `TestClass` -> which means `foo` is null while `TestTrait` is being constructed.

```
Parent (arg = null, foo = null)
          \
           \
    TestTrait (bar = null)           Parent(arg = "hello", foo = "hello")
              \                      /
               \                    /
             TestClass(arg = "hello", foo = "hey")
```

This may *seem* surprising, because dynamic dispatch works the other way around - methods are called on the *most* derived type first, and then on less derived types (if `super.method()` is invoked).

But there's a good reason for this: the initialization of a type often depends on the correct initialization of its base type.

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't think explains the additional context provided in my edit.